# How to hide inline text input in Telegram Bot?

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I use the following [PHP library](https://github.com/TelegramBot/Api) for creating Telegram Bot.
I want to show the buttons without inline input field.
[image]

I'm trying to use **editMessageReplyMarkup** method with empty **reply_markup** object but it doesn't help.

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ ."/vendor/autoload.php";

try {
    $bot = new \TelegramBot\Api\Client('***');
    
    $bot->command('start', function ($message) use ($bot) {

        $keyboard = new \TelegramBot\Api\Types\ReplyKeyboardMarkup([
            [
                ['text' => 'One', 'callback_data' => "one"],
                ['text' => 'Two', 'callback_data' => "two"],
            ]
        ], true, true);


        $bot->sendMessage($message->getChat()->getId(), "Choose the number", null, false, null, $keyboard);
        $bot->editMessageReplyMarkup($message->getChat()->getId(), $message->getMessageId(), []);
    });

   $bot->run();

} catch (\TelegramBot\Api\Exception $e) {
    $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: So you're trying to send regular buttons, instead off inline?

Comment: @0stone0 I'd like to remove "Write a message..." text field and display just the buttons

Comment: I don't think you're able to remove the 'text' field, it's part of the app. Could you maybe share a screenshot of desired outcome?

Comment: If this is an API you get from Github, you have the source. Maybe you can edit the field out of the library source. Alternatively, could you run some JS that hides the field based on its ID?

Comment: @0stone0 probably you're right because I've never seen it's being implemented. But what is [this method](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup) made for then?

Comment: That method is used to alter a message, like remove keyboard, add new buttons etc.